# Julia throws error twice in try-catch block

Tags: julia

Suppose I have the code,

```
try
    throw(ArgumentError("hi"))
catch 
    println("something went wrong")
    throw(ArgumentError("bye"))
end
```

Running this code results in the following output

```
something went wrong
ERROR: ArgumentError: bye
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[31]:5
caused by [exception 1]
ArgumentError: hi
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[31]:2
```

Basically, it throws both the error in the `try` block and the error in the `catch` block.

My understanding of how things *should* work is that `try` should fail, and then it should simply output what's inside the `catch` block.

Can anyone explain what is going on here, and how to rewrite this code so it has the desired functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What happens is exactly what you describe, only the exception thrown by `throw(ArgumentError("bye"))` goes out of the `try`-`catch` block.

The thing you see is caused by the fact that if you have such an "exception caused by exception" Julia prints out whole exception stack via `show_exception_stack` from base/errorshow.jl. In this way you learn that the exception thrown in `catch` block was caused by the exception thrown in `try` block. But this is only for display purposes.

You can check this by wrapping your code in another `try`-`catch` block and investigating what exception goes out from the inner `try`-`catch`:

```
julia> try
           try
               throw(ArgumentError("hi"))
           catch
               println("something went wrong")
               throw(ArgumentError("bye"))
           end
       catch e
           dump(e)
       end
something went wrong
ArgumentError
  msg: String "bye"

julia>
```

Comment: however, it looks like `dump(e)` prints the error message. Basically what I would like is to able to print something prior to the error.

Comment: Can you give an example what you would want to be printed and how. I used `dump` only as an example to print out the representation of `e` so that you can be sure that actually `ArgumentError("bye")` is stored in `e`.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to look at `rethrow()`. The helpstring explains the behavior you're seeing:

(This documentation comes from Julia 1.4):
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.4-dev/base/base/#Base.rethrow

```
help?> rethrow
search: rethrow

  rethrow()

  Rethrow the current exception from within a catch block. The rethrown exception will continue propagation as if it had not been caught.

  │ Note
  │
  │  The alternative form rethrow(e) allows you to associate an alternative exception object e with the current backtrace. However this misrepresents the program state
  │  at the time of the error so you're encouraged to instead throw a new exception using throw(e). In Julia 1.1 and above, using throw(e) will preserve the root cause
  │  exception on the stack, as described in catch_stack.
```

In particular: **In Julia 1.1 and above, using throw(e) will preserve the root cause exception on the stack, as described in catch_stack.**

If you just want to print something before the original exception is propagated, you can use no-argument `rethrow()`:

```
julia> try
           throw(ArgumentError("hi"))
       catch
           println("something went wrong")
           rethrow()
       end
something went wrong
ERROR: ArgumentError: hi
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[9]:2
```

Answer (score 0):

`rethrow(e)` might be what you are looking for. It adds the current backtrace to the alternative exception object `e`.

However, rethrowing an alternative exception should be used with care since it misrepresents the program state at the time of the error (as stated in [Base.rethrow](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.rethrow)).